# Как выбрать слой в подпапке в Photoshop через Python?

Tags: python, photoshop

Имеется `AutoScript.py`, в котором находится скрипт, и `source.psd`, который находится в той же папке, что и скрипт. В файле фотошопа находятся слои-заготовки, которые нужно включать в зависимости от входных данных. Каким образом можно выбирать и включить слой в подпапке?

Пробовал пользоваться `photoshop-python-api`, конкретных примеров навигации по папкам не нашёл, но уверен, что такая возможность в этом api есть, поэтому продолжаю дальше изучать документацию этого api.

Файл фотошопа в скрипте открываю таким образом (на основе примера из документации):

```
import photoshop
import config as conf

    with photoshop.Session(conf.path_to_psd, action="open") as ps:  #conf.path_to_psd из рядом лежащего файла
        #тут должен идти код
        return 0
```